# "Lighthouse failed while trying to load a type: <XXX> Make sure the type is present in your schema definition."

Tags: laravel-dusk, laravel-lighthouse

I'm performing dusk test with lighthouse inside it like:

```
class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testExample()
    {
      //this is a mutation for adding more stuff
      $this->graphQL('mutation ...')

      $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($url) {
            $browser->visit($url)
                //asserts...
      });
    }
}
```

And on my mutations, the error message is:

```
"""Lighthouse failed while trying to load a type: typeFromMySchemaExample \n
\n
Make sure the type is present in your schema definition.\n
"""
```

I've already seen that schema is valid by:

```
php artisan lighthouse:validate-schema
```

And check the schema by it self to see if that type is present with:

```
php artisan lighthouse:print-schema
```

And cleared all configs/cache from laravel and lighthouse as in [solution#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62762401/experiencing-intermittent-errors-when-trying-to-use-laravel-lighthouse-php-with) with no success.

In my composer, I have:

- laravel/dusk in v6.12.0
- nuwave/lighthouse in v5.2.0
- phpunit/phpunit in v9.5.2

ps:I commented that type in the graphql and the error keeps going by my import order in the schema.graphql.