# Does artisan cache:clear also remove lighthouse cache?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I am getting this error in production:

> exception: "Nuwave\Lighthouse\Exceptions\DefinitionException"
> file: "/var/www/app/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/TypeRegistry.php"
> line: 95
> message: "Lighthouse failed while trying to load a type: CreateTicketInput↵↵Make sure the type is present in your schema definition.↵"
> trace: [,…]

and someone advices to clear the Lighthouse cache [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62762401/experiencing-intermittent-errors-when-trying-to-use-laravel-lighthouse-php-with).

But I already used to clear laravel cache with `artisan cache:clear`
So my question is: does `artisan cache:clear` also remove lighthouse cache?

Comment: No. It removes the cached data in storage/framework/cache.

Comment: @Cutis hey, any chance you can remove the "Lighthouse" tag, it won't let me do it after approving an edit suggestion. That tag is used for Google Lighthouse (performance monitoring), not for Laravel Lighthouse. Thanks.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie sorry, I removed it

Answer (score 3):

In theory, yes. In practice, it depends.

[By default](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/blob/8b18d9a380da69ddf369f8a0ea5a196dbc2303c2/src/lighthouse.php#L98-L101) Lighthouse uses the default Laravel cache driver so `artisan cache:clear` should also clear the Lighthouse cache indirectly.

However, if you configured Lighthouse to use a different cache driver than Laravel uses, it will not work.

Long story short: Yes if you use the default cache for Lighthouse `artisan cache:clear` does clear the Lighthouse cache but do not depend on that, use `artisan lighthouse:clear-cache` to be sure that now and in the future (and for any configuration) the cache is properly cleared.

---

It's [very likely](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/pull/1842) that in the next version of Lighthouse the cache method will change and no longer make use of the Laravel cache which makes `artisan cache:clear` no longer affecting the Lighthouse cache so that is another reason to use `artisan lighthouse:clear-cache` too.